# How to sort datagridview column with positive and negative numbers?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

```vb
    Private Sub DataGridViewRez_SortCompare(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewRez.SortCompare
        Dim num1 As Integer
        Dim num2 As Integer
        If e.Column.Index = 3 Then

            If Integer.TryParse(CStr(e.CellValue1), num1) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(CStr(e.CellValue2), num2) Then
                'Order the numbers based on their absolute value.
                e.SortResult = Math.Abs(num1).CompareTo(Math.Abs(num2))
            Else
                '        'At least one of the values is not a number so consider them equivalent for sorting purposes.
                e.SortResult = 0
            End If

            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

tell me how can I do the sorting of the datagridview so that first there are positive values ​​from 0 and higher, then negative ones?

Comment: So you want non-negative numbers in ascending order first and then negative numbers, right? Should the negative numbers be in ascending or descending order, i.e. 0,1,2,-2,-1 or 0,1,2,-1,-2? We shouldn't have to guess this stuff. ALWAYS provide ALL the relevant information.

Comment: Right. First you need positive numbers in ascending order 0,1,2 ..., and then negative -1, -2, -3 ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this should do the trick:

```vb
If (num1 < 0) = (num2 < 0) Then
    'Either both numbers are negative or both are non-negative, so sort on ascending absolute value.
    e.SortResult = Math.Abs(num1).CompareTo(Math.Abs(num2))
Else
    'One is number is negative and one is non-negative, so sort on descending value
    e.SortResult = num2.CompareTo(num1)
End If
```

If you want it as a one-liner:

```vb
e.SortResult = If((num1 < 0) = (num2 < 0), Math.Abs(num1).CompareTo(Math.Abs(num2)), num2.CompareTo(num1))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but in the first place it turns out 10,9,8,7 ... and it should be 1,2,3,4,5 ...

Comment: @Lider13, either it works or it doesn't. I tested the code and it works for me so, if it didn't work for you, you must have done something wrong.